# This method is not supported against a materialized query result

Tags: sql-server, linq

I am trying to link many tables using LINQ Lambda but i am getting problem when dealing with subquery to get a value for ProducedBy property. I am getting a message : **This method is not supported against a materialized query result message**.

Can give me a hand ?

```
            var temp = db.MK_Product_Variant
                .Join(db.MK_Products, a => a.ProductId, b => b.ID, (a, b) => new { a, b })
                .Join(db.MK_Product_Category, c => c.b.CategoryId, d => d.ID, (c, d) => new { c, d })
                .Join(db.MK_Game_Type, e => e.d.GameType, f => f.ID, (e, f) => new { e, f })
                .Where(g=> !db.MK_MP_Variant.Select(h=>h.ID).Contains( g.e.c.a.ID)) /* My Store only */
                .Select(i => new { 
                    Category = i.e.d.Name, 
                    ItemType = i.f.Name, 
                    ItemNo = i.e.c.a.ID, 
                    Enabled = i.e.c.b.Enabled,
                    Status = "", 
                    ProducedBy = (db.MK_Products.Join(db.MK_Production_Resource,k=>k.ID,l=>l.Item,(k,l) => new {k,l})
                    .Join(db.MK_Production_Staff,m=>m.l.Staff,n=>n.ID,(m,n) => new {m,n})
                    .Where(o => o.m.k.ID == i.e.c.a.ID)
                    .Select(p=>p.n.Location).DefaultIfEmpty("").ToList())[0],
                    ReleaseDate = i.e.c.a.ReleaseDate, 
                    ReleasingQty = i.e.c.a.Qty, 
                    Price = i.e.c.a.Price_MKD, 
                    QtyPurchaseFromUser = "", 
                    QtySold = db.MK_Product_VariantHistory.Where(j => j.Variant == i.e.c.a.ID && j.PurchaseDate >= startDate && j.PurchaseDate <= stopDate && !(db.MK_MP_Variant.Select(t => t.ID)).Contains(i.e.c.a.ID)).Count() 
                });
```

and this is the line of codes where i want to use it :

```
            int count = 0;

            foreach (var item in temp)
            {
                result.Add(count, new string[] { item.Category, item.ItemType, item.ItemNo.ToString(), item.Enabled.ToString(), "", item.ProducedBy.Count()==0?"":item.ProducedBy.FirstOrDefault().Country , string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt}", item.ReleaseDate), "", "", item.ReleasingQty.ToString(), "", item.QtySold.ToString(), item.QtyPurchaseFromUser.ToString(), string.Format("{0:#0}", item.Price), "", "", "", "", "" });

                count++;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

where you have `select`, after `where` statement, you return a anonymous type in `select` statement which has a property named `ProducedBy`, to set this property you have written a query and finally, have called `ToList` to get first element...
you need to use `FirstOrDefault` instead `ToList()` and  getting zero index element like this:

```
ProducedBy = db.MK_Products
            .Join(db.MK_Production_Resource,k=>k.ID,l=>l.Item,(k,l) => new {k,l})
            .Join(db.MK_Production_Staff,m=>m.l.Staff,n=>n.ID,(m,n) => new {m,n})
            .Where(o => o.m.k.ID == i.e.c.a.ID)
            .Select(p=>p.n.Location)
            .DefaultIfEmpty("")
            .FirstOrDefault()
```

you can not call `ToList` among linq to entity, unless your date be fetched to memory before, if you want to populate a list among linq to entity in master detail case, you can use `AsEnumerable` instead